# Show PopUp on Mouse Hover and Close it on Mouse Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, markers

I have a code here that create a marker and put it in the map

```
var wholeinfo = "This is my message"


marker = L.marker([lat,long], {
  icon: new L.AwesomeNumberMarkers({
  number: '<font color="black" size = "1">' + code + '</font>', 
  markerColor: anyColor,
  })}).bindPopup(wholeinfo).openPopup().on('click', markerOnClick).on('mouseover', openPopup());

markers.addLayer(marker);
```

I wonder how can I show the popup of that marker when i hover my pointer on it? then close when i remove my pointer. I try this but no luck

`'mouseover', openPopup()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
.on('mouseover', function (e) { this.openPopup(); })
.on('mouseout', function (e) { this.closePopup(); });
```

instead of

```
.on('mouseover', openPopup())
```